# Copy ListView cell value

Tags: wpf, listview

I have `ListView` bind into my collection:

```
<ListView
    Name="listView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding collcection}" />

list<MyData> collcection;
public class MyData
{
   public string Name;
   public string Id;
}

<GridView.Columns>
  <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Vendor Name"/>
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Vendor Id"/>
</GridView.Columns>
```

So i want to able to right click on specific row and copy one of my 2 cells (Name or ID).
is it possible to right click only one cell from specific row and copy its value ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want, you can do something like this:

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding collection}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonUp" Handler="OnMouseRightButtonUp"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSalmon"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

As you can see, i have created Style for TextBlock in ListView resources. TextBlock is control that created by ListViewItem Template.

Codebehind:

```
private void OnMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText((sender as TextBlock).Text);
}
```

Comment: And is it possible what right click on my cell to highlight only the cell that i want and not all row ? or i need o use DataGrid for this ?

Comment: No overload for 'OnMouseRightButtonUp' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler'  --> i need to create this event somewhere ?

Comment: I have added a trigger on IsMouseOver to show highlight sample. You can use and DataGrid too, but as for me it's too heavy and for edit purposes.

Comment: All event handlers in Code Behind

Comment: i try to add MouseRightButtonUp="listView_MouseRightButtonUp" but i still got this error